# How to validate that a number was inputted in a HTMl text box before posting to a php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have written the function **myChecker()** which is supposed to return the value of false and not allow submission if the user has entered a non-number value.

Have I put **onclick="return myChecker();"** it the wrong place?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Coffee Order</title>
    <script language="javascript">
        function myChecker()
        {
            var number1 = document.getElementByName("order").value;

            if(typeof(number1) === 'number')
            {
                alert("Invalid data type; please enter a number");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST"  action="price.php">
        <p>How many supplies of Colombian Decaf would you like to order:</p>
        <input type="text" name="order">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return myChecker();">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: The `onclick` isn't the best way to submit a form
So the `onSubmit` is what I choose

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these have worked so far, I simply keep getting taken to the php page

Comment: Let me know if you can't workout with already provided answers mainly Lixus's answer

Comment: Edited my answer because his `if` is working backwards the way he wants it too.

Comment: Thank you, I almost didn't notice that.

Comment: I'm still having the issue where the function does not run, and I am simply take to the php page

Comment: Any console errors? Try `console.log` your `number1` variable and `typeof()` and see what results it gives you. Also debug your function with a simple `console.log` to see if it's going through.

Comment: thank you, I fixed the issue, I changed name="order" to id="order" and then used getElementById instead

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's supposed to go on the form like this:

```
<form method="POST"  action="price.php" onsubmit='return myChecker();'>
```

Cheers

**EDIT:** Also your `if`conditional is wrong, you are making sure you want your user to enter numbers right? You should change it like this:

```
if(typeof(number1) !== 'Number'){
    alert("Invalid data type; please enter a number");
    return false;
}
```